# How to copy a file to an empty directory through gradle

Tags: javafx, gradle, build.gradle

I'm writing a Javafx Application where I had to include a fxml file to copy from the source to the build directory. This is my task.

```
task copyRequiredFiles(type: Copy) {
    from '/src/com/indywiz/game/ui/view/Game2048.fxml'
    into 'build/classes/main/com/indywiz/game/ui'
}

task (runui, dependsOn: ['classes', 'copyRequiredFiles'], type: JavaExec) {

    main = 'com.indywiz.game.ui.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

If I run runui task, I get `Skipping task ':copy Required Files' as it has no source files.`

What is going wrong? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Below is my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave an absolute part for `from`, but it needs to be a relative path (i.e. no leading `/`).